# How to calculate median from 2 different lists in Python

Tags: python

I have two lists note = [6,8,10,13,14,17] Effective = [3,5,6,7,5,1] ,the first one represents grades, the second one the students in the class that got that grade. so 3 kids got a 6 and 1 got a 17.  I want to calculate the mean and the median. for the mean I got:

```
note = [6,8,10,13,14,17] 
Effective = [3,5,6,7,5,1] 
products = [] for num1, num2 in zip(note, Effective):   
products.append(num1 * num2) 
print(sum(products)/(sum(Effective)))
```

My first question is, how do I turn both lists into a 3rd list:

`(6,6,6,8,8,8,8,8,10,10,10,10,10,10,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,17)`

in order to get the median.

Thanks, 
Donka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For computing the median I suggest you use [statistics.median](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html?highlight=statistics#statistics.median):

```
from statistics import median

note = [6, 8, 10, 13, 14, 17]
effective = [3, 5, 6, 7, 5, 1]

total = [n for n, e in zip(note, effective) for _ in range(e)]
result = median(total)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
10
```

If you look at `total` (in the code above), you have:

```
[6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 17]
```

A functional alternative, using [repeat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
from statistics import median
from itertools import repeat

note = [6, 8, 10, 13, 14, 17]
effective = [3, 5, 6, 7, 5, 1]

total = [v for vs in map(repeat, note, effective) for v in vs]
result = median(total)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach iterating over `Effective` on an inner level to replicate each `number` as many times as specified in `Effective`, and taking the median using [`statistics.median`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.median):

```
from statistics import median

out = []
for i in range(len(note)):
    for _ in range(Effective[i]):
        out.append(note[i])
print(median(out))
# 10
```

Comment: Thank you! very much, I wrote it like this import statistics
from statistics import median
# Use: statistics.mean(liste)
note = [6,8,10,13,14,17]
Effective = [3,5,6,7,5,1]
median(i for i in note for _ in Effective)
print(median) but I got nada in the output

Answer (score 1):

To get your list you could do something like

```
total = []
for grade, freq in zip(note, Effective):
    total += freq*[grade]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [np.repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to get a list with the new values.

```
note = [6,8,10,13,14,17] 
Effective = [3,5,6,7,5,1] 

import numpy as np

new_list = np.repeat(note,Effective)
np.median(new_list),np.mean(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve output like the third list that you expect you have to do something like that:

```
from statistics import median
note = [6,8,10,13,14,17] 
Effective = [3,5,6,7,5,1] 

newList = []
for index,value in enumerate(Effective):
    for j in range(value):
        newList.append(note[index])


print(newList)
print("Median is {}".format(median(newList)))
```

Output:

```
[6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 17]
Median is 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
note = [6,8,10,13,14,17] 
effective = [3,5,6,7,5,1]
newlist=[]
for i in range(0,len(note)):
    for j in range(effective[i]):
        newlist.append(note[i])

print(newlist)
```